# What should I study during the summer?

Tags: education

For a little background, I have always done the bare minimum in school when it comes to any mathematics.  Once I reached college level, though, I found a love for mathematics and I want to keep studying it.  This semester, it finished just a couple days ago, I passed Trigonometry with an A.  I was wondering, how could I continue my education without having to wait 4 months for the summer to end?

I've thought about trying to learn Calculus but I'm not sure where to start.  How could I continue my education?

Comment: You could look up books on calculus , like spivaks calculus which is quite good. You could also use online materials to study more. I'd suggest you also take  a look in next semester course work and proceed from there

Comment: I would like to look at my next semesters course work but it's not available until day 1 of class, unfortunately.  But I'll try looking around for some calculus books.

Comment: Try calculus and real analysis. Have a look at Spivak's book, it's good. If you find this interesting, proceed to the well-known "Baby Rudin": that is "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin.

Comment: I read a review that I shouldn't read Spivak's book if I haven't had initial exposure to Calculus.  Should I read it anyways?

Comment: For someone who just learned trig, it might be a very tough jump to Spivak's Calculus. Gilbert Strang's [Calculus course](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/) and textbook (free online) might be a more accessible introduction to calculus. Three Blue One Brown's [Essence of Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr) videos look good and accessible. I'm a fan of Cohen's Precalculus textbook. Number theory is also fun at this level -- A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory is a good book.

Comment: I've give Giblert Strang's Calculus course a go.  Thanks for the suggestions.